# handling missing data in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a 200,000 x 500 `dataframe` loaded into Pandas. Is there a function that can automatically tell me which columns are missing data? Or do I have to iterate over each column and check element by element?

Once I've found a missing element, how do I define a custom function (based on both the column name and some other data in the same row) to do automatic replacements. I see the fillna() method, but I don't think it takes a (lambda) function as an input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.isnull(frame).any()
```

Is probably what you're looking for to look for missing data

fillna currently does not take lambda functions though that's in the works as an open issue on github.

You can use DataFrame.apply to do custom filling for now. Though can you be a little more specific on what you need to do to fill the data? Just curious what the use case is.

Comment: Thanks! I used this for a Kaggle competition; we were given a dataset with music ratings from different users and we had to build a model that would predict how these users would rate new tracks from different artists.  One of my features for the classifier was to look at the average rating given to a particular artist from that specific user. But if the user had never heard that artist before, that entry would show up as a missing value in Pandas. So in this case I would replace that missing value with the average rating given to that artist (a bad first approximation, better to use the SVD)

Comment: Ah I see. I'm guessing you have something like users as the index and artist/track as a MultiIndex of columns? It depends on the size of your DataFrame, but potentially you could repeat the mean rating so it's the same size as the ratings matrix and then use the NA mask to replace the missing values?

Comment: close; I did a read_csv on the training data, but I didn't choose an index. I built the features by using the pandas group operations, then applied the mean() on the group, and finally did a merge back onto the main dataframe. Some of the features use data from multiple columns, so I just grouped with those column labels, and then merged again (with multiple indices). Thanks for cython-izing the merges :) For the missing data, I had to manually loop over the column and use get_value / set_value, it's not the most efficient way, but it works.